# Pass delegate Action<T> explicitly to the method instead of anonymously

Tags: c#, delegates

Let's say I'm adding a DbContext to services by dependency injection like this :

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));
```

How do I do that explicitly by providing Action delegate to the AddDbContext method with new Action<> ?

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(new Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> ??? );
```

What to write instead of '???'

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do that?

Comment: I'd like to understand the syntax of this method AddDbContext() better and of using Action delegate on the fly.

Comment: If you have a function whose signature matches the Action's signature, you can just pass it by name, or you can do it the old fashioned way by passing `new Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>(YourFunctionName)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the delegate in multiple ways.
Anonymous lambda (your original)

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));
```

Manually create an `Action<>`. But why anyone would want to do that?

```
var action = new Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(action);
```

Local or regular function

```
void Configure(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection"));
}

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(Configure);
```

`Action<>` as a variable

```
var configure = (DbContextOptionsBuilder options) => 
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection"));
}; 

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(Configure);
```

Comment: ok great. What if I was forced to do this : 
`builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(new Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> ??? )` 
Is there a way ?

Comment: `builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(new Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>(Configure)`